# Replace spaces with &nbsp; in C#

Tags: c#, string

If I'm not sure about the number of spaces, How can I replace the Spaces After `<br />` with `&nbsp;`

```
 string Text = "3 stunning private villas <br />   The Beach villa";
 if (Text.Contains("<br /> "))
 {
   Text = Text.Replace("<br /> ", "<br />&nbsp;");
 }
```

Comment: what's wrong with the current code?

Comment: @sujithkarivelil this only replaces the 1st space

Comment: @sujithkarivelil it only replaces one whitespace and not x number of whitespaces behind the <br /> so `<br />     ` should replace to `<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

Comment: Side note: `if (Text.Contains("<br /> "))` is redundant and can be eliminated: `Text = Text.Replace("<br /> ", "<br />&nbsp;");`

Comment: so 10 spaces should be replaced with 10 &nbsp; ?

Comment: you mean all spaces ? or ony spaces after a ´<br />´

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace *all* (white) *spaces* (i.e. all kind of spaces, tabulations etc.) which are after the `<br />` you can try using *regular expressions*:

```
  string Text = "3 stunning private villas <br />   The Beach villa";

  string result = Regex.Replace(
      Text,
    @"(?<=\<br \/\>)\s+",
      match => string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("&nbsp;", match.Length)));

  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  3 stunning private villas <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;The Beach villa
```

Comment: Note that `\s` matches more than just a space character, which strictly speaking goes against the question.

Comment: @canton7: it's an open question for me. If we have "<br />&sp;&nbsp;&sp;"  I think more correct to turn all (white) spaces into non-break ones: "<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"

Comment: I see you've now addressed it at the beginning of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a regex:

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=<br */>) +", m => m.Value.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"))
```

The `+` means "a space one or more times". This matches the spaces after the `<br />`

The `(?<=<br */>)` is a positive lookbehind assertion. This makes sure that the regex only matches things that appear immediately after the `<br />`. I added a variable amount of spaces between the `<br` and the `/>` to be safe.

Every time this finds one or more spaces immediately after a `<br />`, it takes those spaces and replaces each one with `&nbsp;`, and substitutes those back into the original string.